# Error deploying Node/Angular app in Heroku server

Tags: node.js, angular, heroku, package.json

I'm trying to deploy my Node/Angular app in Heroku server and the **log file** doesn't give any usefull information.

I have try to change Node and npm version, I followed the steps in https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/troubleshooting-node-deploys and nothing happended

This problem don't allow me to init the application an then I can't know whether the server works or I have some mistake.

```
...///...

-----> Creating runtime environment
  
...///...
       
-----> Installing binaries
...///...

       
-----> Restoring cache
...///...
       
-----> Installing dependencies
...///...
       
-----> Build
       Detected both "build" and "heroku-postbuild" scripts
       Running heroku-postbuild
       
       > opord-easy-app@0.0.0 heroku-postbuild
       > ng build --configuration production
       
-----> Build failed
       
       We're sorry this build is failing! You can troubleshoot common issues here:
       https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/troubleshooting-node-deploys
       
       If you're stuck, please submit a ticket so we can help:
       https://help.heroku.com/
       
       Love,
       Heroku
       
 !     Push rejected, failed to compile Node.js app.
 !     Push failed
```

This is my **package.json** file.

```
{
  "name": "opord-easy-app",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "node server/index.js",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e",
    "dev": "nodemon server/index.js",
    "heroku-postbuild": "ng build --configuration production"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~11.2.9",
    "@angular/cdk": "^11.2.9",
    "@angular/cli": "^12.0.1",
    "@angular/common": "~11.2.9",
    "@angular/compiler": "~11.2.9",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~11.2.9",
    "@angular/core": "~11.2.9",
    "@angular/forms": "~11.2.9",
    "@angular/material": "^11.2.9",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~11.2.9",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~11.2.9",
    "@angular/router": "~11.2.9",
    "@ngx-translate/core": "^13.0.0",
    "@ngx-translate/http-loader": "^6.0.0",
    "@types/ol": "^6.4.2",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "heroku": "^7.54.0",
    "mongoose": "^5.12.7",
    "morgan": "^1.10.0",
    "ol": "^6.5.0",
    "ol-ext": "^3.1.19",
    "rxjs": "~6.6.0",
    "tslib": "^2.0.0",
    "typescript": "~4.1.5",
    "zone.js": "~0.11.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.1102.8",
    "@angular/cli": "^12.0.1",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~11.2.9",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.6.0",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "codelyzer": "^6.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.6.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~5.0.0",
    "karma": "~6.1.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage": "~2.0.3",
    "karma-jasmine": "~4.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.0",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.7",
    "protractor": "~7.0.0",
    "ts-node": "~8.3.0",
    "tslint": "~6.1.0",
    "typescript": "~4.1.5"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "14.x",
    "npm": "7.7.6"
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you checked if its showing any error when trying to access the application over the URL

Comment: Yes I have. Nothing happens. The server is not up